# Does php image creation functions have any color trouble?

Tags: php, image, php-gd

I'm using the following snippet: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4254-PHP-Render-graphical-diagrams-of-hierarchical-trees.html

And I'm adding a png image to each node. If i get it correctly the code used is:

```
$strSourceImage = imagecreatefrompng($node->image);
imagecopyresampled($this->img, $strSourceImage, $node->x, $node->y, 0, 0, $node->w, $node->h, $this->imgsize[0], $this->imgsize[1]);
```

But the png image get its colors altered,

This is the original image: http://postimg.org/image/jz4hjej4f/2e34cb9e/
and this is the result when adding it through php: http://postimg.org/image/mzkw9uwlf/0959e1b9/

Comment: You may have figured it out, but it's likely because you need to use the `imagecreatetruecolor` function

Answer (score 0):

Got it. The img was being created with imagecreate(), im using now imagecreatetruecolor(), hope this helps someone in the future.